# jQuery - <script> videos using tabs not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm trying to use tabs with  videos but is not working

Here is what I've tried so far:

jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#sidebar").tabs({
        event: "click",
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            var _tab = ui.newTab;
            $('#sidebar li').removeClass('active');
            $(_tab).addClass('active');
        },
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Video1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Video2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Video3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3714373/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3745793/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3745040/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}
#sidebar li a {
    color:#000;
}
#sidebar li.inactive a {
    color:#FF0000;
}
#sidebar li.active a{
    color:#00FFFF;
}

#tabs-2 div, #tabs-3 div {
     height: 390px !important; // I think the problem is here
}
```

Here is demo link:http://jsfiddle.net/UnYx9/12/

Problems:

- Sometimes it doesn't load the videos
- Sometimes it doesn't show the videos

Also I will appreciate if you suggest me any better way to do this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja I'm trying to use videos inside tabs but I don't have problem with iframe videos I have only with <script> videos

Comment: Do you want to play the videos when you switch in to the tab?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja It doesn't really matter

Comment: The problem is that your not using video tags, you using some external player, and I'm not sure if there's a way to to it with the player

Comment: @SpeedyNinja do you know any other way to do this, It is not necessary to be tabs, what I want is just to have a href links for each video and by clicking them to select the video content div

Comment: Not really sure, but it might be possible to just insert the players with JavaScript